# inputenc when we write in english

Tags: input-encodings, paper

I will submit a paper in mathematic to a journal. I write it in english.

Can I delete the following code

```
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Or I should replace it by another codes?

I ask this question, because some times when I want to open my tex file, I couldn't open it and I get this message. But when I change the folder of my tex file, it will be opened without any problem.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: you should keep T1 and use whatever input encoding you use: utf8 in preference to latin1, or if you only use ascii input then you can drop inputenc

Comment: the simplest thing is to write exactly what you wrote, unless you have a specific reason to change it.

Comment: Thank you: that is I use the following code? :\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   because some times I find problems with 'inputenc' when I write in french

Comment: If you are writing in French you should definitely use inputenc. If you "have problems" then presumably you made an error but if you do not show any error message impossible to guess about that.

Comment: you have to specify with inputenc the file encoding that your editor used to save the file, we can not tell you what encoding that is.

Comment: I have edited my question in order to see the problem and thank you.

Comment: that is a completely separate issue, using non-ascii caracters in file names, it is simplest just not to do that. There is absolutely no way anyone could have guessed that was the issue from your original question. that is why questions should always have a complete test document, and if they are about an error message have the complete error (preferably as text from the log file, not as an image)

Comment: your image also shows you are using `\bf` don't do that!

Comment: The error message you’re getting is unrelated to the document’s contents. It’s due to your editor not being able to read certain paths (that presumably use Unicode characters). Summary: It’s a crap editor; get a modern one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your document really is saved in latin1 (ISO-8859-1) encoding then it is perfectly OK to leave

```
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

however latin1 is mostly regarded as a "legacy" encoding, and most operating systems and editors will (or should) default to UTF-8 (Unicode) encoding these days. If using UTF-8 then the lines should be

```
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

If you can guarantee that you only use ASCII input then ASCII, UTF-8 and latin1 are the same encoding in that range so it doesn't really matter, you could delete the `inputenc` line but it is probably better to still specify the encoding your editor is using (which most likely is UTF-8 as noted above).

You should keep the T1 `fontenc` line unless you have specific reason to remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what do you mean by 'ASCII '? Thank you

Comment: @Student  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 4):

As David stated `utf-8` is preferable to `latin1`, to get this you should write

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Instead off

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

However, if you write only in English and don't use utf-8 symbols you could just write:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: Was too slow, did'nt see David's answer, and cannot delete mine from the phone